# How to Post to database via RestKit 0.20

Tags: ios, json, restkit, afnetworking

I am trying to POST to an API using restkit.
When I press save post- I get an error showing an empty post and alert saying:

```
Expected status code in (200-299), got 422" UserInfo=0xb83ca20 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"body":["can't be blank"]},
```

The post is displayed in the tableView but the text I entered doesn't make it to the database.
Any ideas why this might be? The usual problems I've seen are because people are missing parsing the data to json or because they lack a responseDescriptor - but I have this and I'm not getting the json error. It's just not retaining the text I enter.
Why is this?

My savePost method is like this

```
RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
Post *post = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
[post setBody:self.postTextField.text];
[objectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext save:nil];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager]; [manager postObject:self path:@"/posts.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Success saving post");
   // [MUser setCurrentUser:self];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure saving post: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

And in my appDelegate I have this setup:

```
 NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Markofresh" ofType:@"momd"]];
    // NOTE: Due to an iOS 5 bug, the managed object model returned is immutable.
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] mutableCopy];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    // Initialize the Core Data stack
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSPersistentStore __unused *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addInMemoryPersistentStore:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store: %@", error);

    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

    // Set the default store shared instance
    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

    // Configure the object manager
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fierce.herokuapp.com"]];
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
    [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:@"application/json"];
    [objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/json"];


    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];
    //setup Post Entity map
    RKEntityMapping *entityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id":             @"postID",
     @"url":            @"jsonURL",
     @"body":           @"body",
     @"created_at":     @"createdAt"}];
    entityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"postID" ];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping pathPattern:@"/posts.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[entityMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[Post class] rootKeyPath:@"/posts.json"];
    [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

I have seen other people get hung up on this and wonder if maybe AFNetworking might be a better choice for this kind of simple method- and there's more documentation on it as well.
I know what I'm trying to do is simple and I don't get what is causing the empty post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be doing:

```
[manager postObject:post path:@"/posts.json" parameters:nil  ...
```

So your issue is simply a typo?

---

Try turning on mapping trace logging so you can see what's happening:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

And think about something like the [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to show you exactly what's hitting the wire.

Comment: it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I have 'post' or 'self' - I get the same error. I thought it might be that the parameters are nil - and that I should pass in a parameter for post or body.text like in rails- but I haven't figured out a way to do that so I might be on the wrong track. Any other ideas?

Comment: so I already had the RKLogLevelTrace in the appDelegate file and when I copy it to the Post file I get a more verbose log when it GETs the data but the same response from the failed POST. I got CharlesProxy like you said and it will take me a second to understand it but what I can see is that I have 5 incomplete Requests made- thought I'm not sure how exactly they are incomplete..

Comment: So Charles allows you to look at the request you send and the response received in detail. So you can see all the headers and the full body of the GETs and POSTs. You need to know what the server expects obviously but it provides a way to verify the true data being transmitted.